# Использование ES6 в серверном проекте на NodeJS

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babel

Написан серверный проект на `NodeJS`, используется штатный его синтаксис, хотелось бы подключить `ES6` синтаксис в своём проекте, в частности `import express from 'express'` и т.д.

В проекте используется `Express` и `SocketIO`, в качестве `API` соответственно.

---

Для себя нашёл несколько вариантов:

- Использование другого расширения для файла `.js` -> `.mjs`
- Указав `"type": "module"` в `package.json`
- Подключение `Webpack` + `Babel`.

*Насколько мне известно, то Webpack это сборщик, он собирает проект в один или несколько бандлов, плюс переводит код из нового стандарта в более старый.*

Но нужен ли он в таком проекте, который будет работать только на бэкенде?

---

Подскажите необходимые технологии для создания каркаса для данной задачи

Comment: обновить версию node.  насколько помню 14  версия уже поддерживает импорты. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854169/how-can-i-use-an-es6-import-in-node

Comment: @СергейПетрашко обновил до 15.*. Всё с этим нормально, я про `"type": "module"` уже написал, я просто спрашиваю можно ли и нужно ли использовать `Webpack` + `Babel` или нет

Comment: Я запускал без вебпака.

Comment: @СергейПетрашко я тоже, но правильно ли это.. и если нет то как лучше

Comment: трудный вопрос. наверное даже философский))))